# How to suggest the next word of a key-phrase in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elastic-stack

I'm rather new to ElasticSearch and was wondering if there's a way to implement an auto-completion feature for key-phrases in documents.

Assuming I have documents like below:
doc 1: "...Neural Network Project..."
doc 2: "...Neutral Reaction of Chemical..."

and if the query is "neu" then I want it to return:
"Neural"
"Neutral"
"Neural Network"
"Neutral Reaction"

I have tried Phrase Suggester which only does spell-checking on the input phrase.
I've also tried Completion Suggester which has 2 major shortcomings for the mentioned senario:
1- Completion Suggeter is based on the prefix of the query and documents, meaning if the target word-phrase is in the middle of the sentence, the document wouldn't be returned as a result.
2- It returns characters limited by "Max_input_length" parameter as the result, meaning the results won't be in a word-phrase form like "Phrase Suggester".
P.S. I'm aware of the fact that I can add input/output parameters to Completion Suggester to fix these issues but the number of documents in my index are massive and possibly growing which makes this task very time-consuming and also inaccurate.

Now I was wondering, is there a workaround for this? Is there a different ES functionality I should be looking for or it just cannot be done by built-in ES functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in the right ballpark of what Elastic recommends. Their [official example setup](https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/solutions/ecommerce/autocomplete) uses [Term Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/search-suggesters.html#term-suggester) instead of [Phrase Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/search-suggesters.html#phrase-suggester) in case that gets you closer to your use case. (Their docs have various products as back-ends (e.g. AppSearch, Workplace Search, Elasticsearch) so linking the [Elasticsearch tutorial](https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/tutorials/elasticsearch).)

Alternatives towards the same end-goal from Elasticsearch: [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester) (same doc ballpark you're talking), [autocomplete analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/search-analyzer.html) ([more info](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/elasticsearch-auto-complete-guide/))

Alternative Elasticsearch examples from community: [manual string check](https://coralogix.com/blog/elasticsearch-autocomplete-with-search-as-you-type/) ([same but only check as prefix](https://codecurated.com/blog/create-a-simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch/), [with fuzziness](https://taranjeet.medium.com/elasticsearch-using-completion-suggester-to-build-autocomplete-e9c120cf6d87))